# Grub wont detect windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, windows

My system is a dual boot system with Fedora (190 GB), Kubuntu (30 GB) and 700 GB with no OS. I decided to delete Fedora and format it using Windows 10 NTFS. After I install Windows 10 (190 GB) it doesn't show up in GRUB, but Kubuntu and Fedora are still showing. If I click *Fedora*, it will only show the boot up screen and nothing will happen.

I tried `sudo update-grub` with no luck.

Window 10 is not detected by `os-prober`:

[image: does not detect in os-prober]

However, it is shown in `fdisk -l`:

[image: it detect drive of windows 10]

Comment: Are both systems UEFI? You show a bios_grub which is for Ubuntu in BIOS boot mode and an ESP - efi system partition which both Ubuntu & Windows use for UEFI boot. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair Also make sure Windows fast start up is off. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: UEFI i think i install a windows 10 uefi base on rufus, i dont know if kubuntu or fedora is uefi  tried boot-repair https://ibb.co/SfjvWph

Comment: Reboot installer in UEFI boot mode & then run Boot-Repair. If you used Rufus to create live installer you probably have to recreate it in gpt/UEFI mode, not MBR CSM(nonUEFI) mode.